# I have a list which has been created from another list. However, I do not want two names repeating after each other. How can I do that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

[image: Code]

I have six names in a *list* and wish to repeat them `20` times randomly and save it to a *list* called `lineup`. However, I do not want these names repeating after each other. For example, I would not want something like `['Shadab', 'Shadab'..]` next to each other.

How can I go about fixing that?

I tried to append the names from the `bowlers` list into a new list called `lineup` and after that, use indexing to replace repeatable names. However, I was not able to do that successfully.

Comment: Please update your question with which language you are using.....  :).  Seems to by python.....

Answer (score 0):

This can be the answer code of your question.

```py
import random
### number of overs
overs = 20
bowlers = ['Wasim','Hasan','Fazal','Rumman','Abrar','Shadab']
lineup = []

for i in range(overs):
    lineup.append(random.choice(bowlers))
    if (i != 0) & (lineup[i-1]==lineup[i]):
        lineup.pop()
        bowlers_notprev = bowlers.copy()
        bowlers_notprev.remove(lineup[i-1])
        lineup.append(random.choice(bowlers_notprev))
```

Double for loops should not be used in this case. If the first `for` loop of your code is to add one person to the `lineup` list, and the second `for` loop is to check if it is the same as the previous one, you can also write the code as below.

```py
for i in range(overs):
    z = random.choice(bowlers)
    lineup.append(z)

for x in range(overs-1):
    if lineup[x] == lineup[x+1]:
        rmv = lineup.pop(x)
        bowlers_notprev = bowlers.copy()
        bowlers_notprev.remove(rmv)
        lineup.insert(x, random.choice(bowlers_notprev))
```

And you can use list comprehension like below when sampling `lineup` from `bolwers`.

```py
lineup = [random.choice(bowlers) for a in range(overs)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one more answer without conditional if:

```
import random
### number of overs
overs = 20
bowlers = ['Wasim','Hasan','Fazal','Rumman','Abrar','Shadab']
lineup = []
curr_bowler = random.choice(bowlers)

for i in range(overs):
    lineup.append(curr_bowler)
    bowlers.remove(curr_bowler)        
    last_bowler = curr_bowler
    curr_bowler = random.choice(bowlers)
    bowlers.append(last_bowler)
```